# Using groupby to calculate cum sum in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have dataframe below which I intended to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['SR01','SR01','SR02','SR01','SR01','SR02'],
                 'User':['101','101','101','102','102','102'],
                 'Year':['2018','2019','2019','2018','2019','2019'],
                 'Month':[12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 2],
                 'Qty':[10, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6]})
```

My intended output is like below:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['SR01','SR01','SR02','SR01','SR01','SR02'],
                 'User':['101','101','101','102','102','102'],
                 'Year':['2018','2019','2019','2018','2019','2019'],
                 'Month':[12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 2],
                 'Qty':[10, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6],
                'CumSum': [10, 8, 3, 4, -1, 6]})
```

However when I use `df_a.groupby(['Location','User','Year','Month']).sum().groupby(level=1).cumsum()`, i get this instead:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['SR01','SR01','SR02','SR01','SR01','SR02'],
                 'User':['101','101','101','102','102','102'],
                 'Year':['2018','2019','2019','2018','2019','2019'],
                 'Month':[12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 2],
                 'Qty':[10, 8, 4, -1, 11, 5]})
```

Can somebody explain why my code is not working and solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
df_a.groupby(['Location','User']).Qty.cumsum()
0    10
1     8
2     3
3     4
4    -1
5     6
Name: Qty, dtype: int64

df_a['cumSum']= df_a.groupby(['Location','User']).Qty.cumsum()
```

Comment: hi, is there a way where i can do it while maintaining the other columns as well?

Comment: @rain123 you can just assign it back , also check the update

Comment: oh great! this is exactly whati wanted. thanks for your help!

Comment: @rain123 Yw :-), btw  would you like upvote and accept ?